# Getting "Expected an identifier" and "missing ';' before '.'" in class with a struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm trying to make a gradebook program. I'm in the early part of defining a class for gradebooks, which are vectors of structs, and each struct has a string for a student's name and a vector of that student's grades. Here is the gradebook.h header:

```
// Creates a gradebook database that can be accessed and modified

#ifndef GRADEBOOK_H
#define GRADEBOOK_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class gradebook {
public:
    //--constructors
    gradebook();
    // post: An empty database is constructed

    //--modifiers
    void add_student(string name);
    // post: A new student is added who has the given name

    bool remove_student(string name);
    // post: If the name matches an existing student, that student is removed.
    // Otherwise, return false.

    void add_grades();
    // post: Adds grades input from the keyboard

    //--accessors
    void show_total_grade(string name);
    // post: Displays the cumulative grade for the student. If no student by
    // that name, display a message conveying such.

    void show_class_average();
    // post: Displays the average grade for the class.

    void show_student_grade(string name);
    // post: Displays grades for all assignemnts for the given student.

    void show_assignment_grade(int assignment);
    // post: Displays all the grades for the given assignment number.

    //--iterator functions

    struct book_entry
    {
        string my_name;
        vector<double> grades;

    book_entry(string name)
    {
        my_name = name;
        vector<double> grades;
    }

    void get_student(string name) {
        cout << my_name << ": ";
        for (auto &i : grades)
            cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;

    }
};

private:
string my_student_name;
string my_assignment;
vector<book_entry> my_book;
double my_grade;
};

#endif
```

And the implementation:

```
#include "gradebook.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;

//--constructors
gradebook::gradebook() {

vector<book_entry> my_book;
}
//--modifiers
void gradebook::add_student(string name) {
//my_book.next() = 
}

//--accessors
void gradebook::show_student_grade(string name) {
book_entry.get_student(string name);
}

void gradebook::show_assignment_grade(int assignment) {

}

//--iterator functions
```

I'm using MSVS 2013, and when I build the project, I get an error on line 23 of the implementation (`book_entry.get_student(string name);`). The error is "missing ';' before '.'". The period in that line has a squiggly red underline, and if I hover over it, I get a different error: "expected an identifier". It seems I am misunderstanding how to use the struct I've set up. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do I fix that? It has a semicolon after the last curly brace.

Comment: I have two; one at the end of the struct, just before the private data section, and the other after that, before the `#endif`.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
book_entry.get_student(string name);
```

to

```
book_entry.get_student(name);
```

Also, `book_entry` should be a object available within this scope. The code you show does not have it rather your first code snippet says it is a *type* rather than a object.

Comment: Yes. That's one problem.

Comment: I made that change, and it underlined `name`, saying that it is not a type name. As for the second issue you raise, how do I change that?

Comment: That is the correct fix for this line. See if you get a compiler error. You may have confused intellisense.